# Unit cost function for CES

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, mathematical-economics

You do not need to make computations, you can just tell me how to make the following derivation:

I'm studying a paper where the unique final good of the economy is produced according to the following CES function:

[image]           $[1]$

where $y(i)$ is the intermediate product $i$ and the $\sigma>1$  is the EoS between these intermediate products. Here, we have horizontal innovation, i.e., an increase in the number of intermediate varieties, $N_t$, represents a source of technological progress.

We set $P_Y=1$, i.e., the final output is the numeraire good.

Then, we get the demand for each product $i$ by equating the marginal product of product $i$ with the corresponding price, $p(i)$. Note: now I suppress the subscript time just for the sake of notation:

$y(i) = p(i)^{-\sigma}Y$

Then, each intermediate product $y(i)$ is produced in monopolistic competition, by a single firm, as follows:

[image]   $[2]$

each intermediate product $y(i)$ is producing by employing either low skilled labor,$l(i)$ or machines $x(i)$ and high skilled labor, $h(i)$. $l(i)$ and $x(i)$ substitutes with elasticity $\epsilon>1$, and $\alpha(i) \in \{0,1\}$. $\alpha(i)$ is an indicator function taking value $1$ if the firm is automated and taking value $0$ otherwise. $\tilde{\varphi}$ is a productivity parameter for machines.

Suppose that there is no R&D sector and technology evolves exogenously. Then, the paper says **from equation $[2]$, the unit cost of production is given by:**

[image]

Could you tell me how to derive $[3]$?